# CodeIgniter http://127.0.0.1 page not found problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’ve recently started with Codeignigter on local windows machine.

I have install the IIS and extracted only ci folder and place index.php, application, system and user_guide  in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot.

I've made change in the application/config/config.php  to  $config['base_url'] = "http://127.0.0.1/";
now i am trying to excess   http://127.0.0.1 and http://127.0.0.1/index.php but it shows page not found.

Can anyone tell me how can i fix this Or what else i have to install

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell IIS what to do with .php extension by configuring handler mapping (ie pass to fastcgi).

For IIS 7, click [here](http://www.interiders.com/2008/02/09/set-up-iis-7-w-mysql-and-php-5/).
For IIS 6, click [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/248/configuring-the-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60/).